# How to apply Linger option with winsock2

Tags: c++, windows, winsock2

I want to avoid the TIME_WAIT state when closing a TCP socket (I am aware of the [pros and cons](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html) of circumventing TIME_WAIT).

I am using Windows and WinSock2/.Net sockets and am having great difficulty getting the `SO_LINGER` socket option to work as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/ns-winsock-linger).

My test code with most of the error checking removed for brevity is:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "starting..." << std::endl;

  WSADATA w = { 0 };
  int error = WSAStartup(0x0202, &w);
  if (error || w.wVersion != 0x0202) {
    std::cerr << "Could not initialise Winsock2." << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  auto clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

  // Set socket options
  linger lingerOpt = { 1, 0 };
  setsockopt(clientSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, (char*)&lingerOpt, sizeof(lingerOpt));

  linger checkLingerOpt{ 0 };
  int optLen = sizeof(checkLingerOpt);
  int getOptResult = getsockopt(clientSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, (char*)&checkLingerOpt, &optLen);
  if (getOptResult < 0) {
    wprintf(L"Failed to get SO_LINGER socket option on client socket, error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Linger option set to onoff " << checkLingerOpt.l_onoff << ", linger seconds " << checkLingerOpt.l_linger << "." << std::endl;
  }

  // Bind local client socket.
  sockaddr_in clientBindAddr;
  clientBindAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  clientBindAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
  clientBindAddr.sin_port = htons(15064);
  bind(clientSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&clientBindAddr, sizeof (clientBindAddr));

  sockaddr_in serverSockAddr;
  serverSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serverSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
  serverSockAddr.sin_port = htons(5060);

  // Connect to server.
  connect(clientSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&serverSockAddr, sizeof (serverSockAddr));

  std::cout << "connected." << std::endl;

  Sleep(1000);

  //shutdown(clientSocket, SD_BOTH);
  closesocket(clientSocket);

  std::cout << "finished." << std::endl;
}
```

Result:

```
starting...
Linger option set to onoff 1, linger seconds 0.
connected.
finished.
```

The sample above does avoid the TIME_WAIT state but does so because the client socket sends a RST packet.

[image: Wireshark capture]

If the `Linger` option is changed to:

```
linger lingerOpt = { 1, 5 };
```

Result

```
starting...
Linger option set to onoff 1, linger seconds 5.
connected.
finished.
```

Then closing the socket does result in a TIME_WAIT but of 30s which is the same result as not setting the `SO_LINGER` option.

[image: netsh time wait]

[image: wireshark time wait]

Another observation is that if the socket is shutdown (which is the recommended way to cleanly close) with `shutdown(clientSocket, SD_BOTH);` then the Linger option of `{1,0}` will have no affect.

In summary:

- Set Linger option as {1,0} & close with closesocket => RST.
- Set Linger option as {1,5} & close with closesocket => FIN-ACK & TIME_WAIT of 30s.
- Set Linger option as {1,0} & close with shutdown, closesocket => FIN-ACK & TIME_WAIT of 30s.
- Set Linger option as {1,5} & close with shutdown, closesocket => FIN-ACK & TIME_WAIT of 30s.

What I'd like is:

<strike>Set Linger option as {1,0} & close with shutdown, closesocket => FIN-ACK & TIME_WAIT of 0s.</strike>

**Update:** As pointed out in the [closesocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-closesocket) reference by `Remy Lebeau` a Linger option of {nonzero,0} is hard coded to generate a RST.

A short TIME_WAIT of a few seconds would be just as good, i.e. a linger option of {1,1} caused `closesocket` to exit gracefully with a 1s TIME_WAIT period, and which according to the `closesocket` documentation should be possible.

**Update 2:** As again pointed out by `Remy Lebeau` the Linger option and TIME_WAIT period are NOT linked. If you're reading this you probably made the same mistake I did and were trying to shorten the TIME_WAIT period via `setsockopt` and `SO_LINGER`.

By all accounts that can't be done and in cases where careful consideration judges TIME_WAIT needs to be avoided (such as in my case where the application layer protocol can deal with stray or orphaned TCP data packets) the ideal option looks to be a Linger setting of {1,0} to force a hard `RST` socket close which will allow the connection to be immediately re-attempted without the OS blocking the attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really avoid `TIME_WAIT` when your app is the one closing the TCP connection first (`TIME_WAIT` does not happen when the peer closes the connection first). No amount of `SO_LINGER` settings will change that fact, other than performing an abortive socket closure (ie sending a `RST` packet). It is simply part of how TCP works (look at the [TCP state diagram](https://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/debugging-tcp.html)). `SO_LINGER` simply controls how long `closesocket()` waits before actually closing an active connection.

The only way to prevent the socket from entering the `TIME_WAIT` state is to set the `l_linger` duration to 0, and don't call `shutdown(SD_SEND)` or `shutdown(SD_BOTH)` at all (calling `shutdown(SD_RECEIVE)` is OK).  This is [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-closesocket):

> The closesocket call will only block until all data has been delivered to the peer or the timeout expires. If the connection is reset because the timeout expires, then the socket will not go into TIME_WAIT state. If all data is sent within the timeout period, then the socket can go into TIME_WAIT state.
>
> If the l_onoff member of the linger structure is nonzero and the l_linger member is a zero timeout interval on a blocking socket, then a call to closesocket will reset the connection. The socket will not go to the TIME_WAIT state.

The real problem with your code (aside from the lack of error handling) is that your client is `bind()`'ing a client socket before `connect()`'ing it to a server.  Typically, you should not `bind()` a client socket at all, you should let the OS choose an appropriate binding for you.  However, if you must `bind()` a client socket, you will likely need to enable the `SO_REUSEADDR` option on that socket to avoid being blocked when a previous connection boudn to the same local IP/Port is still in `TIME_WAIT` state and you are trying to `connect()` in a short amount of time after the previous `closesocket()`.

See [How to avoid TIME_WAIT state after closesocket() ?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.winsock.programming/md6bsoy08Fk) for more details.  Also, [the document you linked to](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html) in your question also explains ways to avoid `TIME_WAIT` without resorting to messing with `SO_LINGER`.

Comment: Thx, must have skipped over the closesocket details. I don't get the described behaviour with l_onoff nonzero and l_linger nonzero. For all my attempts the TIME_WAIT is always 30s. I skipped the context but I do need to always bind to the same well known port and I am setting SO_REUSEADDR (it's a SIP server app and TCP connections must originate from port 5060). Even with SO_REUSEADDR there is no immunity from connect errors if the exact socket pairs are in a TIME_WAIT state. .

Comment: The time that `closesocket()` waits before closing the connection (the `SO_LINGER` timeout) is a separate duration than the time the connection stays in the `TIME_WAIT` state after it is actually closed. You can't set the timeout of `TIME_WAIT` itself (without resorting to platform-specific system settings), its duration is dictated by the TCP standard. And I'm familiar with how SIP works, SIP **servers** listen on port 5060, but SIP **clients** are NOT required to connect to the server from port 5060, they can use any source port they want. So again, `bind()` before `connect()` is not needed.

Comment: Ah got it now. I was stuck in a rut thinking the purpose of the linger option was to influence the TIME_WAIT period. It's a SIP server acting as a client to other SIP servers. Port 5060 will typically be whitelisted. 99% of traffic is UDP so no drama. The last 1% requiring TCP origination from a single port is the drama.

Comment: Again, a SIP client socket does not need to be bound locally to port 5060 before connecting to a server listening on port 5060. Your app being a SIP server that uses a client socket to connect to other SIP servers does not change that.

Comment: In this case if the SIP TCP connection originates from port 5060 it gets accepted. If it originates from a random port it gets blocked. It's a policy setting.